# Scrapy behaviour while scraping many urls in loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a website annd extracting urls from one page than from the extracted ones but when I run the loop for 1 date i.e only once and break it the data is extracted efficiently and is correct but when there is loop of dates of 8 months I noticed that the dates were moving by one number counitinously but data was not extracted yet. My question is this behaviour of scrapy itself or there is something wrong in my code. I this is scrapy way of doing things will my data be correct and complete? And if there is mistake in my code what is it.
The code is

```
import scrapy, os, time#, json
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "timeline"

    def start_requests(self):
        dates = ['2021-02-01', '2021-02-02', '2021-02-03', '2021-02-04', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-06', '2021-02-07', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-09', '2021-02-10', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-12', '2021-02-13', '2021-02-14', '2021-02-15', '2021-02-16', '2021-02-17', '2021-02-18', '2021-02-19', '2021-02-20', '2021-02-21', '2021-02-22', '2021-02-23', '2021-02-24', '2021-02-25', '2021-02-26', '2021-02-27', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-02', '2021-03-03', '2021-03-04', '2021-03-05', '2021-03-06', '2021-03-07', '2021-03-08', '2021-03-09', '2021-03-10', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-12', '2021-03-13', '2021-03-14', '2021-03-15', '2021-03-16', '2021-03-17', '2021-03-18', '2021-03-19', '2021-03-20', '2021-03-21', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-23', '2021-03-24', '2021-03-25', '2021-03-26', '2021-03-27', '2021-03-28', '2021-03-29', '2021-03-30', '2021-03-31', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-03', '2021-04-04', '2021-04-05', '2021-04-06', '2021-04-07', '2021-04-08', '2021-04-09', '2021-04-10', '2021-04-11', '2021-04-12', '2021-04-13', 
        '2021-04-14', '2021-04-15', '2021-04-16', '2021-04-17', '2021-04-18', '2021-04-19', '2021-04-20', '2021-04-21', '2021-04-22', '2021-04-23', '2021-04-24', '2021-04-25', '2021-04-26', '2021-04-27', '2021-04-28', '2021-04-29', '2021-04-30', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-06', '2021-05-07', '2021-05-08', '2021-05-09', '2021-05-10', '2021-05-11', '2021-05-12', '2021-05-13', '2021-05-14', '2021-05-15', '2021-05-16', '2021-05-17', '2021-05-18', '2021-05-19', '2021-05-20', '2021-05-21', '2021-05-22', '2021-05-23', '2021-05-24', '2021-05-25', '2021-05-26', '2021-05-27', '2021-05-28', '2021-05-29', '2021-05-30', '2021-05-31', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-02', '2021-06-03', '2021-06-04', '2021-06-05', '2021-06-06', '2021-06-07', '2021-06-08', '2021-06-09', '2021-06-10', '2021-06-11', '2021-06-12', '2021-06-13', '2021-06-14', '2021-06-15', '2021-06-16', '2021-06-17', '2021-06-18', '2021-06-19', '2021-06-20', '2021-06-21', '2021-06-22', '2021-06-23', '2021-06-24', '2021-06-25', '2021-06-26', '2021-06-27', '2021-06-28', '2021-06-29', '2021-06-30', '2021-07-01', '2021-07-02', '2021-07-03', '2021-07-04', '2021-07-05', '2021-07-06', '2021-07-07', '2021-07-08', '2021-07-09', '2021-07-10', '2021-07-11', '2021-07-12', '2021-07-13', '2021-07-14', '2021-07-15', '2021-07-16', '2021-07-17', '2021-07-18', '2021-07-19', '2021-07-20', '2021-07-21', '2021-07-22', '2021-07-23', '2021-07-24', '2021-07-25', '2021-07-26', '2021-07-27', '2021-07-28', '2021-07-29', '2021-07-30', '2021-07-31', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-02', 
        '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04', '2021-08-05', '2021-08-06', '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-09', '2021-08-10', '2021-08-11', '2021-08-12', '2021-08-13', '2021-08-14', '2021-08-15', '2021-08-16', '2021-08-17', '2021-08-18', '2021-08-19', '2021-08-20', '2021-08-21', '2021-08-22', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-24', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-26', '2021-08-27', '2021-08-28', '2021-08-29', '2021-08-30', '2021-08-31', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-03', '2021-09-04', '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08', '2021-09-09', '2021-09-10', '2021-09-11', '2021-09-12', '2021-09-13', '2021-09-14', '2021-09-15', '2021-09-16', '2021-09-17', '2021-09-18', '2021-09-19', '2021-09-20', '2021-09-21', '2021-09-22', '2021-09-23', '2021-09-24', '2021-09-25', '2021-09-26', '2021-09-27', '2021-09-28', '2021-09-29', '2021-09-30']
        a_file = open("C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\scrapy\\bookstoscrape\\bookstoscrape\\spiders\\file.txt", "r")
        list_of_lines = a_file.readlines()
        global done_date, done_player, done_times
        done_date = eval(list_of_lines[0])#empty lists
        done_times = eval(list_of_lines[1])
        done_player = eval(list_of_lines[2])
        a_file.close()
        global player_urls
        player_urls = set()
        while set(dates) != set(done_date):
            try:
                for date in dates:
                    if date in done_date:
                        continue
                    global dateG
                    dateG = date
                    url = 'https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?r_date=' + date + '&blocks=header%2Cmeetings'
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
                    done_date.append(date)
                    a_file = open("C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\scrapy\\bookstoscrape\\bookstoscrape\\spiders\\file.txt", "r")
                    list_of_lines = a_file.readlines()
                    list_of_lines[0] = str(done_date) + "\n"
                    a_file = open("C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\scrapy\\bookstoscrape\\bookstoscrape\\spiders\\file.txt", "w")
                    a_file.writelines(list_of_lines)
                    a_file.close()
                print(player_urls)
                with open('links.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(player_urls)

            except Exception as e:
                print(player_urls)
                time.sleep(30)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('parsing')
        json_data = response.json()
        global timelines_url, raceids
        timelines_url = []
        raceids = []
        
        for data in json_data['meetings']['tracks']['2']['races']:
            a = 1
            for i in data['races']:
                if int(i['trackId']) == 4:
                    if a == 1:
                        lstt = i['rTime']
                        time = lstt.split(' ')
                        time = time[1].replace(":","%3A")
                    a = a + 1
                    timelines_url.append("https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?race_id=" + i['raceId'] + "&track_id=4&r_date="+ dateG +"&r_time="+ time +"&blocks=meetingHeader%2Cresults-meeting-pager%2Clist")
                    raceids.append(i['raceId'])
            if  a == 1:
                for data in json_data['meetings']['tracks']['1']['races']:
                    a = 1
                    for i in data['races']:
                        if int(i['trackId']) == 4:
                            if a == 1:
                                lstt = i['rTime']
                                time = lstt.split(' ')
                                time = time[1].replace(":","%3A")
                            a = a + 1
                            timelines_url.append("https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/results/blocks.sd?race_id=" + i['raceId'] + "&track_id=4&r_date="+ dateG +"&r_time="+ time +"&blocks=meetingHeader%2Cresults-meeting-pager%2Clist")
                            raceids.append(i['raceId'])

        for t in timelines_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(t, self.parse2)
    def parse2(self, response):
        print("parsing2")
        jsn_data = response.json()
        for i in range(len(raceids)):
            try:
                for datas in jsn_data['list']['track']['results'][raceids[i]]:
                    dog = datas['dogId']
                    if dog in done_player:
                        continue
                    tm = datas['msgTimeOff']                
                    tm = tm.split(' ')
                    player_urls.add("https://greyhoundbet.racingpost.com/#results-dog/race_id="+ raceids[i] +"&dog_id="+ dog +"&r_date="+ dateG +"&track_id=4&r_time=" + tm[1])

                    done_player.append(dog)
                    a_file = open("C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\scrapy\\bookstoscrape\\bookstoscrape\\spiders\\file.txt", "r")
                    list_of_lines = a_file.readlines()
                    list_of_lines[2] = str(done_player)
                    a_file = open("C:\\Users\\Roshaan\\Desktop\\scrapy\\bookstoscrape\\bookstoscrape\\spiders\\file.txt", "w")
                    a_file.writelines(list_of_lines)
                    a_file.close()
            except Exception as e:
                if e == "KeyError":
                    continue
                else:
                    i = i-1
                          
                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'timeline'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

I am new to scrapy. Thanks in advance
**Note**: I noticed a new thing that dates are unorderd somtimes request for month for exmple 4th month is in process the next momoent it is 3rd month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behavior because scrapy is asynchronous by default. Try to set concurrent_requests to 1:

```py
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "norgren"

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
    }
...
...
...
```